# What browser event does a screen reader use when pressing a button or link?

Tags: browser, accessibility, dom-events, screen-readers

I've yet to setup a screen reader to test myself, but I'm wondering what specific browser event does a screen reader use when clicking a button or a link?

Is it the equivalent of a mouse click or tabbing to the element and pressing enter or space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screenreaders will trigger the `click()` event, but screenreader users may still use their keyboard, mouse, trackpad or braille display.

See [SCR35: Making actions keyboard accessible by using the onclick event of anchors and buttons](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR35.html)

> While "onclick" sounds like it is tied to the mouse, the onclick event is actually mapped to the default action of a link or button. The default action occurs when the user clicks the element with a mouse, but it also occurs when the user focuses the element and hits enter or space, and when the element is triggered **via the accessibility API**.

Comment: Ahh okay, so it's best to cover all bases then.  Part of the reason I'm wondering is for google analytics tracking.  It seems their basic click tracking doesn't cover enter/spacebar/non-mouse click.  Does the screen reader literally run a javascript click event, because I've noticed google analytics doesn't count these under click tracking.

Comment: @cabey This uses the accessibility API (directly handled by the browser). This should not have any consequence on google analytics tracking.

Comment: So, in theory, could a screen reader user click on an element, say a div, with no enter or spacebar event attached to it?

Comment: @cabey If the custom element has `tabindex=0`, the click event will be triggered if it's originated from the screenreader. The problem is more on the opposite that for a custom control, the enter key will not natively work (but that is without a screenreader).

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the education.  I presume all kinds of accessibility are helpful, including support for keystrokes.